# Properties of physical vector field vector field whose components depend only on the distance from origin

Tags: vector-fields, mathematics

In introductory physics, we often have fields of form $ \vec{F} = \frac{k}{r^n} \hat{r}$. This leads me into the habit that all physical vector fields of radius dependent on inverse power of $r$ must always be radial but is this actually true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not always the case and it depends on what you're looking for. A counter-example is the magnetic field generated by an infinitely long wire. The intensity goes with $1/r$ (not the 3-D $r$, but $r$ nonetheless), but it's not a radial field, it circles around the axis of the wire. You con expect radial fields when there's spherical symmetry like for a point charge or a charged sphere.

Comment: Good counter example